# In Bash shell, why does Python complain about printing non-ascii characters only when the output is redirected or piped?

Tags: python, bash

Printing the terminal:

```
> python -c 'print u"\xae"' # no complaints here!
®
```

Printing to a file:

```
> python -c 'print u"\xae"' > tmp.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error also occurs when piping to `cat`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it can't guess the encoding properly and assumes that it's "ascii". Encode to UTF-8 when the output is not a TTY.

Comment: But why is this not a problem with the TTY?

Comment: It uses `$LANG` et alia to get the encoding for the terminal.

Comment: how can this be done in pracyice (detecting if the output is piped?)